# PHP adds a space when echo

Tags: php, echo, space

When I do this:

```
$route .= '<a class="over" onclick="update("'.$info->getData("code").'", "code", "yes")">'.$expl[$b].'</a> ';
} else {
$route .= '<a class="over" onclick="update("'.$info->getData("code").'", "code", "yes")">'.$expl[$b].'</a>, ';
```

The output is:

```
<a class="over" onclick="update(" bv", "code", "yes")">Beverwijk</a>
```

Why is there an space before `bv`? I don't want that.

Comment: What does `var_dump($info->getData("code"));` output?

Comment: `trim($route)` works ?

Comment: where did you find a space?

Comment: do you mean THAT SPACE? `'</a>, ';`

Comment: The space is at update("<HERE IS THE SPACE> bv", "code", "yes");

Comment: trim already tested, not working. vardump:string(2) "BV" NULL NULL string(3) "HLM" NULL string(3) "CAS" string(3) "HLO" string(3) "AMR" NULL NULL string(3) "HLM" NULL string(3) "CAS" string(3) "HLO" string(3) "AMR" NULL

Comment: Unclear which space is the problem, but I assume it's the one at " bv". Either way, the only explanation is that `$info->getData("code")` includes that space already, as it is nowhere in the actual code otherwise. Try what Amal said to see for yourself.

Comment: I think you have this before the code you've shared:    `$route=" ";`

Comment: That doesn't explain why the space appears in the middle of the string. If what you say is correct, it would add a space at the start of the string, not in the middle prior to the update() arguments. That being said, I don't see how the space can appear if your value actually is a string(2) containing BV.

Comment: When I remove the ""  the space is now at: update(BV, "<HERE IS THE SPACE>code", "yes")

Comment: It might be something that happens after the code you have given us. Can you post the code that comes between the supplied code and where it outputs `$route`?

Comment: do you really sure that this space added during execution of code in answer? try to do `echo $route;` after `.=`

Comment: The code before and after the given code:http://pastebin.com/2j5Nakuu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue...
The thing is, when you have double quotes on a quoted attribute, it seems to do that.

```
<a class="over" onclick="update(" bv", "code", "yes")">Beverwijk</a>
                        ^--bad--^
```

**Solution**: use single quotes on the function parameters, escaping them.

```
$route = '<a class="over" onclick="update(\''.$info->getData("code").'\', \'code\' \'yes\')">'.$expl[$b].'</a>, ';
```

Result:

```
<a class="over" onclick="update('BV', 'code' 'yes')">Beverwijk</a>,
```

Hope this helps.